# How do i fix curl linker errors

Tags: c++, curl, c++17, node-libcurl

i'm trying to use libcurl in my C++ application, but i'm running into linker errors.
I did add the include and lib folder in my project and added the .lib file in the additional dependencies.

Error: `LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function _main`

Comment: are you using the static or dynamic version of the libraries? If you have the static one you need to set `CURL_STATICLIB` as preprocessor variable

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm using the static version. I added CURL_STATICLIB but now i get alot of other errors.

https://cdn.thoo.nl/KyCVblTd5AAmf0p8YYHG.png

Comment: @thoo Please don't post image links. They die and it's unhelpful for others who find your post and have similar issues.